# 0 Spring Hibernate-sessionfactory is null while trying to save employee object

Tags: spring

Getting following error when trying to save the `Employee` object. Kindly help.

> [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)
>
> 20:26:06,296 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)
>   com.javapapers.spring.Employee@1ee17a5
>
> 20:26:06,315 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 20:26:06,317 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   com.javapapers.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:17)
>
> 20:26:06,319 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   com.javapapers.spring.EmployeeController.employee(EmployeeController.java:41)
>
> 20:26:06,321 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 20:26:06,323 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> 20:26:06,324 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> 20:26:06,325 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> 20:26:06,326 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
>
> 20:26:06,326 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>
> 20:26:06,327 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
>
> 20:26:06,328 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:502)
>
> 20:26:06,328 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:465)
>
> 20:26:06,329 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>
> 20:26:06,330 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:863)
>
> 20:26:06,330 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
>
> 20:26:06,331 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>
> 20:26:06,332 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:756)
>
> 20:26:06,333 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>
> 20:26:06,333 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>
> 20:26:06,334 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>
> 20:26:06,334 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>
> 20:26:06,335 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>
> 20:26:06,335 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>
> 20:26:06,336 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>
> 20:26:06,337 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>
> 20:26:06,337 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>
> 20:26:06,338 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>
> 20:26:06,338 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>
> 20:26:06,339 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>
> 20:26:06,339 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>
> 20:26:06,340 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>
> 20:26:06,341 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Include you configuration please.

Comment: Please provide `EmployeeDAOImpl` class and spring context configuration files.

Comment: I guess you didn't wire the `EntityManager` or `SessionFactory` correctly, but you really have to post the code at indicate where's the NPE thrown from...